# Creating tensor from a swift array

Tags: swift, tensorflow, swift-for-tensorflow

This works fine:

```swift
import TensorFlow
var t = Tensor<Float>([[1, 0], [0, 1]])
```

But the following gives an error

```swift
import TensorFlow
var a = [[1, 0], [0, 1]]
var t = Tensor<Float>(a)
```

```
error: expression type 'Tensor<Float>' is ambiguous without more context
var t = Tensor<Float>(a)
        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Why does this happen? Also how does one create a Tensor from arrays in swift.

Comment: what is Tensor<Float>? if it is typeOf [[1, 0], [0, 1]] you can just write a = t without typecast

Comment: Tensor<Float> creates a Tensor. Type of [[1,0],[0,1]] is Array<Array<Int>>. I want a tensor and not an array.

Comment: and what if you will write var a: Tensor<Float> = [[1, 0], [0, 1]] ?

Comment: Does `var t: Tensor<Float> = a` actually work? I did not expect that...

Comment: @Swair because use of SomeClass(myClass) really means SomeClass.init(typeOf: Any), you can write an extension and add your own init func to type cast Array<Array<Int>>

Comment: @Sweeper you're right. It doesn't only `var aa: Tensor<Float> = [[1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0]]` does.

Comment: @AlexandrKolesnik I see. So i can extend Tensor to have another init which acceps an Array<Float>?

Comment: We are limited only by our imagination

Comment: ok what I don't get is, `var aa: Tensor<Float> = [[1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0]]` works, and type of `[[1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0]]` is `Array<Array<Double>>`. At the same time `var b: Array<Array<Double>> = [[1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0]]
` and `var bb: Tensor<Float> = b` doesn't work. This is strange.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your first code works because it uses *literals*, as opposed to an already declared variable (whose type is already determined) to initialise the `Tensor<Float>`. Literals get special treatment by the compiler.

The overload of `Tensor.init` that you are calling is [this](https://www.tensorflow.org/swift/api_docs/Structs/Tensor#init_:_1). In your case, it accepts a `ShapedArray<Float>`.

[`ShapedArray`](https://www.tensorflow.org/swift/api_docs/Structs/ShapedArray.html) conforms to the protocol `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`, which means that the compiler can convert an array literal to `ShapeArray` implicitly. However, this is only limited to *literals*, such as `[[1, 0], [0, 1]]`, not identifiers referring to a variable of an array type, such as `a`. `a`'s type is inferred to be a `[[Int]]` by the compiler, and the compiler cannot implicitly convert a `[[Int]]` to `ShapedArray<Float>`.

Though less important, the fact that `Float` conforms to `ExpressibleByIntegerLiteral` (hence `1` and `0` can be converted to a float) also plays a role in allowing your code to compile.

The reason why `var aa: Tensor<Float> = [[1.0, 0.0], [1.0, 0.0]]` works is because `Tensor` also conforms to `ExpressibleByArrayLiteral`.